# Get XML into JavaScript Array, then get the values and write them

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I've been looking around for a while and have found things close to but not what I'm looking for.

I'm try to take this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document name="New Document">
    <url>http://nsc-component.webs.com/Office/Editor/new-doc.html?docname=New+Document&titletype=Title&fontsize=9&fontface=Arial&spacing=1.0&text=&wordcount3=0</url>
</document>
```

I know it's not valid, it's just an example

And make it into a JavaScript array that writes it like so:

```
<a href="URL-TAG-VALUE">NAME ATTRIBUTE HERE</a>
```

For each `<document>` tag

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably parse the XML string before working with it :

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    var parser = new DOMParser(),
    xml = parser.parseFromString(your_xml_string_here,"text/xml");
} else { // Internet Explorer
    var xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

    xml.async = false;
    xml.loadXML(your_xml_string_here); 
}
```

Then you can access the DOM of the XML like you would HTML:

```
var arr = [],
    documents = xml.getElementsByTagName('document');

for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a'),
        url    = documents[i].getElementsByTagName('url')[0];


    anchor.href = url.innerText || url.textContent;
    anchor.innerHTML = documents[i].getAttribute('name');

    arr.push(anchor);
}
```

Your XML as it's shown in the question is not valid, and will however fail the parsing.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBa4F/)

Comment: That's awesome! But would it work for **every** `<document>` tag that was in the XML?

Comment: @brandonjordan - Yes it would, see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBa4F/5/)

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thanks so much! I know I've asked for a lot so far but is there anyway I can put that into a `<div>`, add an `<img/>` before it, some `&nbsp;`'s? If not can I **at least** add a class so I can style it?

Comment: @brandonjordan - you can add anything you want, and build whatever HTML suits your needs. Here's another [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBa4F/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Although your XML isn't valid, and jQuery is not a solution for everything, it does have a nice function called `jQuery.parseXML()`. Here's a possible solution:

```
//assign the XML string to a variable
var xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0"?><document name="New Document"><url>http://stackoverflow.com</url></document>';

//use jQuery's XML parsing function and assign it to a variable
var xmldoc = $.parseXML(xmlstring);

//allow jQuery to handle the elements like HTML
var xml = $(xmldoc);

//find <url> and get its contents
var url = xml.find('url').text();

//find <document> and get its name attribute
var doc = xml.find('document').attr('name');
```

In this example, url will return `http://stackoverflow.com` and doc will return `New Document`.

Comment: Using jQuery will avoid some cross-browser issues with parsing XML.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that once I have some time to edit my code

Comment: any chance you could make an example on jsfiddle? et cetera? pardon. I'm not too fluent in jQuery.